# c++ task won't execute after while loop

Tags: c++

C++ newbie here. I'm not sure how to describe this but the task outside of the `while-loop` won't execute immediately. I need to enter the input value again to get it done.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int fourDigitInt, firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit, i = 0;

    cout << "Enter a 4-digit integer  :  ";
 
    cin >> fourDigitInt;


    while (fourDigitInt > 9999 || !(cin >> fourDigitInt))
    {

        i++;
        if (i >= 3)
        {
            cout << "You do not seem to understand the program instruction.\nPlease try again later." << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {

            cout << "Error: Please make sure you are entering a 4-digit integer" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(4, '\n');
            cout << "Enter a 4-digit integer  :  ";
        }
    }

    firstDigit = fourDigitInt / 1000 % 10;

    secondDigit = fourDigitInt / 100 % 10;

    thirdDigit = fourDigitInt / 10 % 10;

    fourthDigit = fourDigitInt / 1 % 10;

    cout << "1st digit  :  " << firstDigit << endl;
    cout << "2nd digit  :  " << secondDigit << endl;
    cout << "3rd digit  :  " << thirdDigit << endl;
    cout << "4th digit  :  " << fourthDigit << endl;
}
```

Here are some problems I encountered:

1)If I enter a `string` first, it doesn't have any problem.
2)But if I enter any number less than 9999, it won't execute the calculation unless I
enter it again.
3)If I enter a 5-digit number the `endl` won't work. It will just display `Enter a 4-digit integer  :  Error: Please make sure you are entering a 4-digit integer` which suppose to be a different line.

Where exactly did I do wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `while (fourDigitInt > 9999 || !(cin >> fourDigitInt))` -- Where did you get the idea to write code like this?  Explain what this does, because my eyes are glazed over looking at this.  This is either wrong, or being too cute for its own good.

Comment: one thing I notice right away is the placement of `i++`. It should be inside of the `else`.

Comment: `unless I enter it again` of course!! you put a `!(cin >> fourDigitInt)` in the condition of the while loop, that is effectively reading a number from stdint.

Comment: Why not simply test if `fourDigitInt` is between 1000 and 9999, inclusive, and do that test immediately after inputting the value?  The loop is convoluted and frankly, hard to understand without standing on your head.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie it's because the question needs it to be a 4-digit integer so I thought `fourDigitInt > 9999` would mean if the user enters anything number larger than 9999. I don't know if it makes sense...

Comment: `cin >> fourDigitInt;  if (fourDigitInt < 1000 || fourDigitInt > 9999) { mistake, try again }` -- And you keep looping on that until the right value is entered.  That is the simplest way to envision how to write the loop.  Seriously, if you said out loud what I just wrote in that little bit of code, that makes more logical sense than the code you wrote.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It does make more sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is in the while loop condition. It should just check for the value of the `fourDigitInt` variable as that is what is important.

Looking closer, you will also be able to notice the fact that the `if` case inside of the loop would check for the second iteration instead of the third. I fixed that as well by moving the `i++` inside of the `else` block.

```
while (fourDigitInt > 9999 || fourDigitInt < 1000) { 
    if (i >= 3) {  
        cout << "You do not seem to understand the program (ironic coming for OC) instruction.\nPlease try again later." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        i++;
        cout << "Error: Please make sure you are entering a 4-digit integer" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a 4-digit integer  :  ";
        cin >> fourDigitInt;
    }
}
```

Any other issues with your code that may occur are not related to this question.